# Linux buffer cache for DVD/FUSE?

Tags: linux, caching, filesystems, linux-kernel, vfs

I want to know whether the buffer cache in Linux kernel is present for file systems like UDF for DVD and FUSE?

I tried to search for this but unfortunately found little information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buffer cache will be used for any access to a filehandle opened against a block device, unless the file handle is opened with `O_DIRECT`. This includes accesses on behalf of FUSE filesystems. Note that if FUSE does caching as well (I don't know offhand), this may result in double-caching of data; unlike normal in-kernel filesystems, with FUSE the kernel can't safely overlap the page and buffer caches. In this case it may be worthwhile to consider using `O_DIRECT` in the FUSE filesystem daemon to reduce cache pressure (but be sure to profile first!).

For in-kernel filesystems such as UDF, the buffer cache will be used for all IO. For blocks containing file data, the block will simultaneously be in both the buffer and page caches (using the same underlying memory). This will be accounted as page cache, not buffer cache, in memory usage statistics.